# Pandas - Create New Attribute and Value for Groups by Dividing EAV Format Data

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 105],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','items', 20],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','sales$', 355],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','items', 50],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', np.nan],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','items', np.nan],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','sales$', 170],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','items', 35]]

columns = ['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method', 'Attribute', 'Value']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)
```

| Store | Date | Payment Method | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 355 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | items | 50 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | items | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 170 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | items | 35 |

I would like to create a new attribute, called "average item price", which is generated by, for each Store/Date/Payment Method, dividing the sales$ by the items (e.g. for store 5123, 2021-01-01, cash, I would like to create a new row with an attribute called "average item price", with a value equal to 5.25).

I realize that I could pivot this data out, and have one column for sales, one column for items, and divide the two columns, then restack, but is there a better way to do this without having to pivot?

| Store | Date | Payment Method | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | average item price | 5.25 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 355 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | items | 50 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | average item price | 7.10 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | items | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | average item price | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 170 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | items | 35 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | average item price | 4.86 |

Comment: I'd go for your propose approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot` and then `append` after assigning the "Attribute" as needed:

```
pivoted = df.pivot(["Store", "Date", "Payment Method"], "Attribute", "Value")
output = (df.append(pivoted["sales$"].div(pivoted["items"])
                    .rename("Value").reset_index()
                    .assign(Attribute="average item price"), ignore_index=True)
          .sort_values(["Store", "Date", "Payment Method"])
          .reset_index(drop=True)
          )

>>> output
    Store                 Date Payment Method           Attribute       Value
0    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card              sales$  355.000000
1    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card               items   50.000000
2    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card  average item price    7.100000
3    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash              sales$  105.000000
4    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash               items   20.000000
5    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash  average item price    5.250000
6    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card              sales$  170.000000
7    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card               items   35.000000
8    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card  average item price    4.857143
9    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash              sales$         NaN
10   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash               items         NaN
11   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash  average item price         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_table` to get the sum of sales/items per group, then compute the average value and `merge` with the original data:

```
s = (df.pivot_table(index=['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method'],
                    columns='Attribute', values='Value', aggfunc='sum')
       .assign(avg=lambda d: d['sales$']/d['items'])
       ['avg']
     )

df.merge(s, left_on=['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method'], right_index=True)
```

output:

```
   Store                 Date Payment Method Attribute  Value       avg
0   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash    sales$  105.0  5.250000
1   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash     items   20.0  5.250000
2   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card    sales$  355.0  7.100000
3   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card     items   50.0  7.100000
4   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash    sales$    NaN       NaN
5   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash     items    NaN       NaN
6   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card    sales$  170.0  4.857143
7   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card     items   35.0  4.857143
```

##### concat

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index=['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method'],
                      columns='Attribute', values='Value', aggfunc='sum')
         .assign(Attribute='average item price',
                 Value=lambda d: d['sales$']/d['items'],
                 )
         .reset_index()
       )

(pd.concat([df,df2])
   .sort_values(by=columns)
   [columns]
 )
```

Output:

```
   Store                 Date Payment Method           Attribute       Value
0   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card  average item price    7.100000
3   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card               items   50.000000
2   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card              sales$  355.000000
1   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash  average item price    5.250000
1   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash               items   20.000000
0   5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash              sales$
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing up my post. Your solution is close, but rather than a new column, I would like to add a new attribute to the Attribute column.

Comment: @edutt then please provide the expected output in your question, but honestly adding summary rows in the middle of the data is bad practice ;)

Comment: Just updated the question with the desired output. And the desire to not add new columns is so that I can query one column and just change the attribute I'm querying as opposed to having to query new columns.

Comment: I think this is pretty much what OP says *I realize that I could pivot this data out, and have one column for sales, one column for items...*

Comment: @edutt I updated the answer (sorry I'm on my to phone, this is not exactly the order you wanted, but I'm sure you can figure it out)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the index, do the computation, and use categoricals to get a sorted output that matches yours:

```py
cols = df.columns[:-1].tolist()
temp = df.set_index(cols)
# computation
summary = temp.xs('sales$', level='Attribute').div(temp.xs('items', level='Attribute'))
# add attribute to index, with a name:
summary = summary.set_index([['average item price'] * len(summary)], 
                            append = True)
summary.index = summary.index.set_names('Attribute', level = -1)
output = pd.concat([temp, summary]).reset_index()
# create categoricals and sort:
dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['sales$', 'items', 'average item price'], ordered = True)
output.Attribute = output.Attribute.astype(dtype)
dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['cash', 'card'], ordered = True)
output['Payment Method'] = output['Payment Method'].astype(dtype)
output.sort_values(cols)

    Store                 Date Payment Method           Attribute       Value
0    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash              sales$  105.000000
1    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash               items   20.000000
8    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash  average item price    5.250000
2    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card              sales$  355.000000
3    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card               items   50.000000
9    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card  average item price    7.100000
4    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash              sales$         NaN
5    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash               items         NaN
10   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash  average item price         NaN
6    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card              sales$  170.000000
7    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card               items   35.000000
11   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card  average item price    4.857143
```

Answer (score 0):

solution 1：

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
        dd1=dd.assign(Value=lambda dd:dd.Value/dd.Value.shift(-1)).head(1).assign(Attribute='average item price')
        return pd.concat([dd,dd1])

df.groupby(['Store','Date','Payment Method'],sort=False).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True).pipe(print)
```

out：

```
    Store                 Date Payment Method           Attribute       Value
0    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash              sales$  105.000000
1    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash               items   20.000000
2    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           cash  average item price    5.250000
3    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card              sales$  355.000000
4    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card               items   50.000000
5    5123  2021-01-01 00:00:00           card  average item price    7.100000
6    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash              sales$         NaN
7    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash               items         NaN
8    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           cash  average item price         NaN
9    5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card              sales$  170.000000
10   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card               items   35.000000
11   5123  2021-01-02 00:00:00           card  average item price    4.857143
```

or you can use pandasql：

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
        return dd.sql("""
        select * from self union all select tb1.Store,tb1.Date,tb1.[Payment Method],'average item price' Attribute,round(tb1.Value/tb2.value,2) as value from (select * from self where Attribute='sales$') tb1 join (select * from self where Attribute='items') tb2
        """)

df.groupby(['Store','Date','Payment Method']).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```